# Make ScrollViewer not scroll unless necessary

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I have a `ScrollViewer` in my WP7 app which contains the items from an `ItemsControl` inside a `StackPanel`.  The `ItemsControl` can generate an arbitrary number of items.

How can I make the `ScrollViewer` scroll **only if** there are enough items generated by the `ItemsControl` to make scrolling necessary?

There's nothing worse than UIs that scroll when dragged, even though there is nothing else to display outside the current viewport!

Comment: Isn't that a problem with your layout? If there there is no empty space there should be no scrolling by default.

Comment: Don't understand.  My `ScrollViewer` sits within a `Grid`, and it scrolls regardless of whether the height of the content is greater than the available space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automatic/built-in way of doing this.

However, assumming that your list items are a fixed size (and so you know how many can be displayed before scrolling is needed) I'd write a converter for the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and bind it to the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ScrollBarVisibility = Auto?

Comment: Yes, `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` defaults to `Auto`.  It still scrolls when it doesn't need to, despite having this setting.